# Displaying 2 columns in one combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an employee table. I want the combobox to present the employee number and city.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Connection c = new Connection();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT employeeNumber, city FROM tblEmployee";

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds, "Employee");

comboBox1.DataSource = ds;
```

That's what I got so far, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I am using windows forms

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way for a combo box with 2 values per line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514698/any-way-for-a-combo-box-with-2-values-per-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Format event to your ComboBox, and in it compose whatever it is you want to show:

```
private void _Combobox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    var x = (DateFilterType)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = /* insert string concatenation stuff here... */;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override `.ToString()` on the class you're binding to the combobox.

```
class MyClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return thing1.PadRight(10) + thing2.PadRight(10);
    }
    public string thing1 { get; set; }
    public string thing2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you do something like

```
List<MyClass> mc = new List<MyClass>();
mc.Add(new MyClass() { thing1 = "blah1", thing2 = "blah2});

comboBox1.DataSource = mc;
```

the text which is displayed in `comboBox1` is `blah1     blah2` (we'll the formatting here is knocking off all my spaces but these strings are supposed to be padded)

and you use whatever value you want from your class as such

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = ((MyClass)comboBox1.SelectedItem).ToString();
}
```

without having to set a value member

Answer (score 0):

In the datatable you, use add a third column with an expression. In this last column do the concatenation of the two other column.

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for expression reference.

After this use this third column to bind your combobox.

Comment: @user2023203 I think this [link here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643808/datacolumn-expression-to-concat-columns-returning-empty) is pretty mutch the same thing as you

Comment: @Brad i never talked about modifying the database... I talked about the datatable